# subsituting one transformer for another

Tags: power-supply, transformer, wall-wart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

I have an eliptical machine that is no longer being manufactured. it appears that the AC to AC adaptor that outputs 24 volts and 3 amperes has stopped working.

I cannot find anyone to fix it.  As a work around I found an old Mattel adapter that outputs 16.2 volts and 955ma.

It appears to be working for the most part.  The panel is lit up again.

May I safely use this as a work around?

And does anyone know who will fix my broken adaptor?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34745/8159) is our canonical "power supply compatibility" question. From there:

> If a device says it needs a particular voltage, then you have to assume it needs that voltage. Both lower and higher could be bad.
>
> At best, with lower voltage the device will not operate correctly in a obvious way. However, some devices might appear to operate correctly, then fail in unexpected ways under just the right circumstances.

The adapter you have (16.2V / 955 mA) is not suitable since your machine wants 24 V / 3 A, and might not be a good work around.

While the machine might seem to work, it's probably running at a reduced performance and the adapter will be overloaded. I wouldn't use this one, but rather find a suitable replacement (one that delivers 24 V and at least 3 A).

Answer (score 0):

You should use great care in replacing power supplies with ones of like capabilities. I am sure that the original manufacturer of the exercise machine rated the 24VAC supply at 3A for a good reason. When you come along with one rated at less than 1A you are asking for a problem. The substitute unit may severly overheat, go into overload cutout mode and in the worst case even catch fire.

You may be able to get further help on how to repair this machine if you post some pictures of what has failed, the types of connections involved and approach this project as a "design in" replacement. Short that this question is dangerously close to a shopping question which would get closed here at the site as being off topic.